# How to automatically download files from Sharepoint via REST API using postman

Tags: json, api, rest, sharepoint, postman

Stuck with a requirement where I have some CSV files in Sharepoint and I need to download them using REST API.

I am using postman for this task. After generating access token and running the REST API

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/YYYFILES/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('test_library/lib')/Files
```

in postman, I am able to see JSON but files are not being downloaded automatically in local system.

Your ideas will be so helpful!

Thanks a ton in Advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add '$value' after '/Files'

Here is an example you can refer to:

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('test_library/lib')/Files('Document1.docx')/$value
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply. Tried the following. Data is being displayed and when i am clicking "Send and Download", the data in the file is being stored in .txt format but not in .CSV format.

Comment: Hi , I am very sorry, according to my test, there is no way to download the .csv format file.

Comment: Hi. Actually, I have developed a groovy code which segregates and creates a file based on text data. encountering other error "{"error_description":"Invalid JWT token. The token is expired."}" now. Have any idea how to resolve this? will be a great help.

Comment: Please try to delete the connection and add it again.